# triple vector product: vector vs gradient

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I think there's a simple explanation for this, but could not find one from a few online searches. The triple vector product and the curl of $\mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{B}$ have very similar forms, however there are additional terms in the differentiation case:

$
\mathbf{A} \times (\mathbf{B} \times \mathbf{C}) = \mathbf{B} (\mathbf{A} \bullet \mathbf{C}) - \mathbf{C} (\mathbf{A} \bullet \mathbf{B}) \\
  \nabla \times (\mathbf{B} \times \mathbf{C}) = \mathbf{B} (\nabla \bullet \mathbf{C}) - \mathbf{C} (\nabla \bullet \mathbf{B}) + (\mathbf{C} \bullet \nabla)\mathbf{B} - (\mathbf{B} \bullet \nabla)\mathbf{C}
$

Can someone explain why? I'm familiar with Einstein notation if that helps. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You end up with twice as many terms because of the product rule.  More explicitly, if you did the proof of each with index notation, they'd start the same but at the step with $A_iB_lC_m$, the analogous factors in the curl identity would be $\partial_i(B_lC_m) = C_m\partial_iB_l+B_l\partial_iC_m$ because of the product rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it might be useful to present way forward that I prefer.  Here, we begin by introducing notation.

Let $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ be Cartesian coordinates.  We designate by $\hat x_i$, a unit vector along the $x_i$ axis and by $\partial_i$ the partial derivative with respect to $x_i$.

Then, using the convention of summing over repeated indices, the $i$'th component of the vector $\nabla \times (\vec B\times \vec C)$ can be written as

$$\begin{align}
\hat x_i\cdot \left(\nabla \times (\vec B\times \vec C)\right)&=\hat x_i\cdot \left(\hat x_j\times (\hat x_k\times \hat x_\ell)\right)\partial_j(B_kC_\ell)\tag 1\\\\
&=\left(\delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell}-\delta_{i\ell}\delta_{jk}\right)\left(B_k \partial_j(C_\ell)+C_\ell \partial_j(B_k)\right)\tag 2\\\\
&=B_i\partial_j(C_j)-B_j\partial_j(C_i)+C_j\partial_j(B_i)-C_i\partial_j(Bj)\tag 3\\\\
&=B_i(\nabla \cdot \vec C)-(\vec B\cdot \nabla)C_i+(\vec C\cdot \nabla)B_i-C_i(\nabla \cdot \vec B) \tag 4
\end{align}$$

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we used the vector triple product rule (presumed established) while in going from $(2)$ to $(3)$ we used the sifting property of the Kronecker Delta.

Since $(4)$ is true for all $i$, then upon multiplying by $\hat x_i$ and summing over $i$, we find the coveted identity

$$\nabla \times (\vec B\times \vec C)=\vec B(\nabla \cdot \vec C)-(\vec B\cdot \nabla)\vec C+(\vec C\cdot \nabla)\vec B-\vec C(\nabla \cdot \vec B)$$

Comment: I figured it was a product rule thing. Thanks! (And thanks to @Bye_world for you're comment). I'll accept this answer, as it directly shows the product rule being used.

Comment: Charlie, you're welcome!  My pleasure.  Pleased this was useful.  -Mark

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\,\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\epsilon_{abc}}$ is the
>   [Levi-Civita Symbol or/and the Levi-Civita Tensor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationSymbol.html).

---

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\vec{A}\times\pars{\vec{B}\times\vec{C}}} & =
\sum_{i}\hat{e}_{i}\bracks{\vec{A}\times\pars{\vec{B}\times\vec{C}}}_{i} =
\sum_{i}\hat{e}_{i}\sum_{jk}\epsilon_{ijk}\,A_{j}\pars{\vec{B}\times\vec{C}}_{k}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{ijk}\hat{e}_{i}\,\epsilon_{ijk}\,A_{j}
\sum_{\ell m}\epsilon_{k\ell m}\,\,B_{\ell}\,C_{m} =
\sum_{ij\ell m}\hat{e}_{i}\,A_{j}\,B_{\ell}\,C_{m}\
\underbrace{\sum_{k}\epsilon_{ijk}\,\,\epsilon_{\ell mk}}
_{\ds{\delta_{i\ell}\,\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\,\delta_{j\ell}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\sum_{ij}\hat{e}_{i}A_{j}B_{i}C_{j} - \sum_{ij}\hat{e}_{i}A_{j}B_{j}C_{i}
\\[5mm] & =
\pars{\sum_{i}\hat{e}_{i}B_{i}}\pars{\sum_{j}A_{j}C_{j}} -
\pars{\sum_{i}\hat{e}_{i}C_{i}}\pars{\sum_{j}A_{j}B_{j}}
\\[5mm] & =
\color{#f00}{\vec{B}\pars{\vec{A}\cdot\vec{C}} - \vec{C}\pars{\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}}}
\end{align}

> The other one is somehow similar. You can take the opportunity to 'play' with the Levi-Civita $\ds{\epsilon_{abc}}$ Symbol.

Comment: "however there are additional terms in the differentiation case ... Can someone explain why?" Where does your post address this?

Answer (score -2):

As stated above, the first expression given is simply product of vectors, which can be expressed in terms of the dot product. The second involves differentiation, acting on a product. The product rule for vector differentiation will inevitably lead to the extra terms.