# Show that $( \nabla \times {\bf G} ) {\bf v} = \nabla \times ({\bf G}^T {\bf v})$ (curl formula)

Tags: tensors, curl

The effect of the curl of a (second order) tensor field $\bf G$ on a constant vector $v$ is defined by the relation

$
( \nabla \times {\bf G} ) {\bf v} = \nabla \times ({\bf G}^T {\bf v})
$

I'd like to derive the RHS of the above relation from the LHS.

***Update***

This is how far I have gotten following the example in [section B.3.5 of this thesis](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/52102974.pdf#page=105). The only problem now is the inconsistency in the index of the partial derivatives in the results of $( \nabla \times  G ) \, {\bf v}$ and  $\nabla \times  ( G^T \, {\bf v})$ i.e. $\frac{\partial G_{ij}}{\partial x_k}$ versus $\frac{\partial G_{ji}}{\partial x_k}$.

$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
( \nabla \times  G ) \, {\bf v}& = \left[({\bf e}_k \partial_k) \times (G_{ij} {\bf e}_i \otimes {\bf e}_j)\right] v_l {\bf e}_l \\
& = \frac{\partial G_{ij}}{\partial x_k} v_l \left[ {\bf e}_k \times ({\bf e}_i \otimes {\bf e}_j)\right] {\bf e}_l \\
& = \frac{\partial G_{ij}}{\partial x_k} v_l \left[ ({\bf e}_k \times {\bf e}_i ) \otimes {\bf e}_j \right] {\bf e}_l \\
& = \frac{\partial G_{ij}}{\partial x_k} v_l \, \epsilon_{mki} \,  ({\bf e}_m \times {\bf e}_j ) \, {\bf e}_l \\
& = \frac{\partial G_{ij}}{\partial x_k} v_l \, \epsilon_{mki} \, \delta_{jl} \, {\bf e}_m \\
& = \frac{\partial G_{ij}}{\partial x_k} v_j \, \epsilon_{mki} \, {\bf e}_m \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
$$

whereas because $G^T = G_{ji} ({\bf e}_i \otimes {\bf e}_j)$

$$
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\nabla \times  ( G^T \, {\bf v}) & = \left[({\bf e}_k \partial_k) \times (G_{ji} {\bf e}_i \otimes {\bf e}_j)\right] v_l {\bf e}_l \\
& = \frac{\partial G_{ji}}{\partial x_k} v_l {\bf e}_k \times \left[   ({\bf e}_i \otimes {\bf e}_j) \, {\bf e}_l \right] \\
& = \frac{\partial G_{ji}}{\partial x_k} v_l {\bf e}_k \times \left[   {\bf e}_i \,  ( {\bf e}_j . {\bf e}_l ) \right] \\
& = \frac{\partial G_{ji}}{\partial x_k} v_l {\bf e}_k \times ({\bf e}_i \,  \delta_{jl}) \\
& = \frac{\partial G_{ji}}{\partial x_k} v_j \, ( {\bf e}_k \times {\bf e}_i ) \\
& = \frac{\partial G_{ji}}{\partial x_k} v_j \, \epsilon_{mki} \, {\bf e}_m \\
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
$$

Comment: You need to say what is the curl of a 2-tensor and what does the transpose of a 2-tensor means. Then use index notation.

Comment: I modified my answer to address the edits on your question.

Answer (score 1):

One thing needs to be clear: $\nabla$ is not a vector. I repeat: nabla is not a vector. In particular, taking the curl is not "doing cross product with $\nabla$".

In the [thesis](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/52102974.pdf#page=105) you referred to, the cross product of a vector $a$ on the left of a (2,0)-tensor $B$ is taken as
$$(a\times B)^{ij}=\epsilon^i{}_{kl}a^kB^{lj}$$
and the dot product of a vector $c$ on the right of a (2,0)-tensor $B$ is defined as
$$(B\cdot c)^i = B^{ij}\delta_{jr}c^r.$$

Now you want to take the curl of a (2,0)-tensor. This is not a standard thing to do, so there may be various definitions depending on the author.

---

**Option 1 (This is what you did, and what I would do, too).**
Looking at formula for the curl of a vector $(\nabla\times v)^i = \epsilon^{ik}{}_l\partial_kv^l$, one is tempted to define the curl of a (2,0)-tensor as
$$(\nabla\times G)^{ij} = \epsilon^{ik}{}_l\partial_kG^{lj}\text.$$
With this definition we obtain
$$\begin{align*}
((\nabla\times G)\cdot v)^i
&= (\nabla\times G)^{ij}\delta_{jr}v^r \\
&= \epsilon^{ik}{}_l\partial_kG^{lj}\delta_{jr}v^r \\
&= \epsilon^{ik}{}_l\partial_k(G^{lj}\delta_{jr}v^r) && \text{(because $\partial_kv^r=0$)} \\
&= \epsilon^{ik}{}_l\partial_k(G\cdot v)^l \\
&= (\nabla\times(G\cdot v))^i
\end{align*}$$
Since you made this coice, this is the result you got to and, as you already noted, there are no transposes at sight.

---

**Option 2.**
Another possible choice (kinda weird if you ask me), is the definition made in [the slides you also gave me](https://www.slideshare.net/seyisulu/3-tensor-calculus-jan-2013/60). There the author deines the curl of a (2,0)-tensor as
$$(\nabla\times G)^{ij} = \epsilon^{ik}{}_l\partial_kG^{jl}\text.$$
(the contraction with the Levi-Civita symbol is on the second index of $G$, rather than the first). With that definition, one gets
$$\begin{align*}
((\nabla\times G)\cdot v)^i
&= (\nabla\times G)^{ij}\delta_{jr}v^r \\
&= \epsilon^{ik}{}_l\partial_kG^{jl}\delta_{jr}v^r \\
&= \epsilon^{ik}{}_l\partial_k(G^{jl}\delta_{jr}v^r) && \text{(because $\partial_kv^r=0$)} \\
&= \epsilon^{ik}{}_l\partial_k((G^T)^{lj}\delta_{jr}v^r) \\
&= \epsilon^{ik}{}_l\partial_k(G^T\cdot v)^l \\
&= (\nabla\times(G^T\cdot v))^i
\end{align*}$$
as you wanted.

In short, you couldn't get to the identity that appears in those slides because the author and you have different definitions for the curl of a $(2,0)$-tensor.

Comment: There appears to be a proof here but I don't understand the final step
https://www.slideshare.net/seyisulu/3-tensor-calculus-jan-2013/60

Comment: @Olumide They can move their $a^\alpha$ inside of the derivative because they ask for $a$ to be a constant vector. This is my condition $\partial_kv^r=0$ (their $a$ is my $v$). Is that the "last step" that you are asking about?
On the other hand, note that a transpose appears in those slides because they defined the curl of a $(2,0)$-tensor differently. Hope that is clear as well. Cheers.

Comment: I've found the answer in a text. (I'll post it tomorrow.) My approach was slightly off. I'm self-taught and a beginner. BTW lots of texts treat nabla the way I do, like a vector, although it is in fact an operator.

Comment: Nice. I'm glad you were able to come to terms with it. I'll check your answer tomorrow, then.

Comment: Also, I'm aware that a lot of people do treat nabla as if it were a vector, and that's why I insist that is a bad practice. Even if it "works" under certain conditions (e.g., the formula you are asking about only works if the vector is constant), it does not work in a lot of cases. Notably, have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877357/triple-vector-product-vector-vs-gradient). Of course, I'm not telling you shouldn't do it: but if you do, please proceed with extra care.